# c3js : Custom region tooltips, hover effects, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, c3

I've been creating a metrics module (using timeseries) with c3js. I'm now trying to plot out events over my metrics data, which are date-spans (startDate to endDate). Using c3js' regions seemed to be a good choice for it, it only took a little tinkering to make them short and appear above of all my graphed data.

Problem is, the actual SVG Group called `g.c3-regions` is automatically displayed behind the graphed data. Makes sense, there hasn't been any real need allow any user interaction with regions. I need it in the forefront, so I can bind `hover` and `click` functions to each event.

I tried doing this with jQuery: `$('.c3-regions').insertAfter('.c3-chart')`, which simply places it in front. Works fine - that is, until my c3js instance re-renders. Then it spits out an error that it's having trouble re-rendering the regions (since they obviously moved)

I've also tried cloning it and putting that in front, but it doesn't seem to copy over the SVG information.

Any help would be truly appreciated, can provide any code samples on request.

Cheers - - Andrew

Comment: Make the stuff you don't want to interact with pointer-events="none".

Comment: @RobertLongson - I've expanded on your comment as an answer. Hope that's ok (have marked it as a community wiki). Cheers!

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't have minded if you just made it your answer. It says more than I did.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Robert Longson's comment, what you want to add is

```
.c3-event-rect {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.c3-chart {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will allow the clicks to go through to the region layer.

Comment: Thanks @potatopeelings & @robertlongson, but unfortunately that disables all my events for the chart though, which I need to hold on to. I figured out that the only way to do this and have both chart and regions interactive was to modify the c3js core a little bit to move `$$.initRegion();` a little later on in the process, so it renders out in the forefront. Then I moved everything well above all my regular chart data, so it doesn't conflict. Maybe this could be a neat little pull request if I build the option into the `.generate` API?